# protractor-selenium scrolling behaviour difference between chrome and firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, protractor

Currently I have specs failing when using firefox. There is a dropdown list on a page that appears when clicking on a button. I then go over each element in that dropdown list.

Now this list is quite long and requires scrolling the page to find all elements, this is not an issue on chrome but on firefox however the dropdown div appears to close right when protractor wants to scroll the next element into view.

I suspect this is because selenium clicks the page or something to start scrolling. (When testing manually I noticed that clicking outside of the dropdown closes that dropdown)

How can I verify if this is what's happening and can this be changed? What steps does selenium really go through when scrolling?

```
public.clickDcdButton = function() {
    log('clicking dcd button', 'yellow');
    return element(by.className('multiSelect')).click();
};

public.setCollections = function(collectionArray) {
    return public.clickDcdButton().then(function() {
        return selectNone.click();
    }).then(function() {
        return collections.each(function(collection, index) {
            H.util.scrollIntoView(collection).then(function() {
                browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(collection), 5000);
            }).then(function() {
                log('into view');
                return collection.getText();
            }).then(function(text) {
                log(text, 'yellow');
                if (collectionArray.indexOf(text.slice(1)) != -1) {
                    return collection.click();
                }
            });
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return public.clickDcdButton()
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wait until the promise is solved :

Try with this logic :

browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(10,10);').then(function () {
    page.Button.click();
})

Comment: I'm already doing that, doesn't work. The problem isn't that I close the dropdown myself too early but that something else is closing it upon scrolling.

Comment: ahh ok, try to add a wait may be the values are not totally loaded

Comment: *apparantly I can't add code in comments, I'll update OP